# Archivos de configuracion de neovim/vim

Tags: javascript, vim

Estoy usando NeoVim y la configuracion lo tengo en un archivo llamado 'init.vim', ahi dentro tengo toda la configuracion y los plugins, la pregunta es, como podría guardar la configuracion en archivos diferentes como por ejemplo

- init.vim
- plug.vim
- plug-config.vim
  como podria ordenarlo sin que vim me deje de funcionar???

Answer (score 0):

El comando para poder agregar otros archivos a tu init.vim es `so` seguido de el path de tu carpeta en donde se encuentre el archivo de configuración, ejemplo `so ~/.vim/plug.vim` y  `so ~/.vim/plug-config.vim`

Si no te funciona puede probar remplazando `so` por `runtime`.